# Can't get the second ID of a DIV programmatically generated

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using fullcalendar, when I click on an event, a created a div (a popup) displays information about the event. In this popup I can modify or delete the event.

To call the event DELETE I did this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.DeleteEventId', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var idEventDelete = $('.DeleteEventId').data('idevent');
.... and ajax.... and success....
```

The div is programmatically generated like that:

```
content: '<div>' + event.text + '</div><div style="margin-right:10px;"><a href="load/' + event.idClient + '" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button">Display</a><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs UpdateEventId" data-idevent="' + event.id + '">Modify</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs DeleteEventId" data-idevent="' + event.id + '">Delete</button></div>'
```

The problem is that the first event can be deleted but next events can't because the ID that is sent to ajax is the FIRST id. Therefore, when I look for the id behind the button, the id is good. For example:
I deleted the ID 27, it works, I want to delete the ID 33, I look for the ID in HTML, it's 33, but when I click on delete ID 27 is sent.

Comment: var idEventDelete = $(this).data('idevent');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
var idEventDelete = $('.DeleteEventId').data('idevent');
```

You are referring to the class assigned to multiple elements and attempting to get the id of a specific element that was clicked.  Change that line to:

```
var idEventDelete = $(this).data('idevent');
```

`$(this)` refers to the specific element that was clicked.